# Problems with IE 11 cache when deploying new versions of webapp

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, caching, internet-explorer-11

**System**

- Browser version: IE 11
- Backend app server: web logic
- Frontend app: Angular 2

**Problem**

When I deploying new versions off my webapp the browser keeps the old app in the browser cache. Only way at the moment is to go manually and clear browser cache which is not possible in productions.

Is there any way handling the problem in IE 11?

1) I have tried adding a meta tag.

`<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />`

which doesn't work.

2) I have been reading also about adding version numbers on all html/js requests, is that a good solution?